# Watch folder for files being Read

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, file-io

I am trying to watch files in a directory to determine when files are opened/accessed.  I thought `FileSystemWatcher` would do the trick using the event `Changed`.

Problem is that some applications do not create a lock on the file they open/access or change either the date modified or date accessed (even after `fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0`).  Notepad for example.  Apparently is makes a copy of the file in memory and plays with it there until you save it.  Nor does it update the Date Accessed.

**How can I monitor a directory of files and be notified when a file is simply opened/accessed by any program (e.g. Notepad)?**  Files may be opened from another computer, not necessarily on the computer running the "watcher".

I found lots of similar questions but did not see one focusing on file "access".

Comment: Have you already tried various notification flags and had them fail? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx)

Comment: Indeed, yes. I set FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter to watch for everything.  It picked up when files were saved/deleted/created etc but no joy with the opening bit.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite normal.  Updating an existing file is quite dangerous since it can cause irretrievable data loss.  A disk error (like disk full) while writing is very bad news.  The common algorithm used:

- rename the original file
- write a *new* file using the original name
- no error: delete the renamed file
- error: delete the new file, rename original file back

Clearly this doesn't cause a Changed event to be raised, no file was changed.

---

Sorry, I didn't read the question well enough.  There is no notification whatsoever for an app just opening a file for reading.  FSW can only detect *changes* to the file system.  There is no ready alternative either, this requires a custom file system filter driver that snoops on driver requests.  Like the kind that SysInternals' ProcMon utility uses.  I'm not aware of such a driver ready for use in a C# program, you can't write them in C# either.  This just isn't a common requirement.

Comment: This introduces a very large amount of overhead when you're making a small change to a file.  You say it's common.  Which programs actually do file writes like this?

Comment: Besides, that, kez is asking about how to get notified when a file is accessed, not renamed/overwritten/changed.  This doesn't answer the question at all (it is useful information, just not an answer).

Comment: @Sam - Mine do, enough said.  The OP needs to figure out how to use the OnRenamed notification in a smart way.  Surely that is the answer you are looking for?  It was implied.

Comment: @Hans Passant, the OP is asking about an app that just reads a file.  How would just reading a file trigger OnRenamed?

Comment: Hmm, okay, got caught by "until you save it".  FSW is useless to detect an app just reading a file.  No alternative either.

Comment: Your answer got me thinking... how about enabling auditing on the computer hosting the files that need to be monitored and then coding something to monitor the event logs for the file audit entries?  Just worried about the performance hit from enabling file auditing alone... even if it does work.  I think you're right about the lack of notification for simply accessing files.  If there is, I suspect anti-virus software would probably cause it to go nuts when scanning folders, etc.